# Is there a way to run @Test(enabled = false) tests forcibly?

Tags: java, testng

There are many tests that are disabled as above, I want to run full suite xml without manually changing the parameter to true which will be a tedious effort. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use an [IAnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) and register it as a [listener](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners).

```
public class RunAllTests implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    public void transform(ITest annotation, Class<?> testClass,
      Constructor testConstructor, Method testMethod) {
        annotation.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using AspectJ and create pointcuts in order to annotate @Test(enabled = false). However I'm not sure what will happened if you annotate with @Test(enabled = true) if there previous was set @Test(enabled = false). You can first verify that before go to AspectJ.